# Swift keyboard won't dismiss by touchesBegan

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am using

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

in order to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps somewhere, but it won't work. And I don't get any errors

My VC is built up: **View > Visual effect view > view > scroll view > uiButton** (it covers the screen and works as a exit/back button to prev VC) **> Designable view** (Here is where my login form is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In interface builder, drag a `tap gesture recognizer` on the view that you want it to dismiss the keyboard after a tap gesture or you can add the gesture by code :

   ```
   -(void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOutside:)];
       gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 
       [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
   }
   ```
2. Add an `IBAction` to the `tap gesture recognizer` for example  `- (IBAction)tappedOutside:(id)sender;`
3. In the implementation file add :

   ```
   -(IBAction)tappedOutside:(id)sender {
      [self.view endEditing:YES];
   }
   ```

Swift:

```
var tap : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: "dismissKeyboard") 
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap) 

func dismissKeyboard() {
   self.view.endEditing(true) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that touchesBegan() won't work on a scroll view

Comment: `var tap : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }`

This did it :)

Comment: @KiwoTew thank you for sharing, I have updated the answer with the `Swift` version

Answer (score 1):

take the textField that opened that keyboard
and try

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

Comment: Turns out that touchesBegan() won't work on a scroll view

Answer (score 0):

**First, Add delegate to your textfiled**

```
yourtextfiled.delegate=self
```

**Second, Set user interaction enable for Your UIScrollview and View**

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
            yourtextfiled.resignFirstResponder()
 }
```

Comment: @Kiwo Tew, Check that tochecsBegan function whether its working or not

Comment: Turns out that touchesBegan() won't work on a scroll view